# ANTLR C target and XMLLib

Tags: c, antlr, libxml2

I have a program written in C which uses XMLLib and a lexer/parser generated from ANTLR.

My includes look like:

```
#include    "MyParser.h"
#include    "MyLexer.h"
#include    "antlr3.h"
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
```

The problem is my program refuses to compile, erroring with:

```
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:19:0,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h:18,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:218,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:1248,
                 from MyProgram.c:4:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/valid.h:276:21: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/valid.h:302:21: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:218,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:1248,
                 from MyProgram.c:4:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:800:19: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:808:0,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h:18,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:218,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:1248,
                 from MyProgram.c:4:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlIO.h:293:19: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h:35,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:218,
                 from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:1248,
                 from MyProgram.c:4:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:961:22: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:967:22: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:1063:54: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘f’
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:1065:3: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘xmlGetExternalEntityLoader’
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:1068:19: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before numeric constant
```

If I don't include the first two includes everything compiles correctly (I replaced my main() function with a simple 'return 0').  Any idea what could be causing this? :(

My compile command looks like:

```
gcc *.c -c -lantlr3c -I/usr/include/libxml2
```

Edit: I installed libxml2-dev package from the Ubuntu package manager if this makes a difference

Comment: Be sure to link against libxml also, passing the `-lxml2` option to the compiler. I tried a generated parser on my machine and unfortunately got the same kind of errors.

Comment: Also posted here: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/s66vo6wor2b47m5b

Comment: what you have included in  MyProgram.c:4: line ..??

Comment: #include <libxml/tree.h>

Comment: I am getting same issue. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some macro problems.  Line 961 of parser.h includes ID, which may be defined in one of your headers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its ok to resurrect the topic, but I was having the same problem for a more simple program even if I tried to use the "-I /usr/include/libxml2".   However, once I passed the linked argument too  the code was able to compile.

The current FAQ of Libxml.org (http://www.xmlsoft.org/FAQ.html )talk about this:

> Developer corner
>
> Troubles compiling or linking programs using libxml2 Usually the
>   problem comes from the fact that the compiler doesn't get the right
>   compilation or linking flags. There is a small shell script
>   xml2-config which is installed as part of libxml2 usual install
>   process which provides those flags. Use
>
> xml2-config --cflags
>
> to get the compilation flags and
>
> xml2-config --libs
>
> to get the linker flags. Usually this is done directly from the
>   Makefile as:
>
> CFLAGS=`xml2-config --cflags`
>
> LIBS=`xml2-config --libs`

Not sure if one year ago was already with this useful tip.